# Everyday i have to restart my mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When i restart my PC (Ubuntu OS) , i have to **restart**  my **mongodb** server.

**(service mongod restart)**

So any way to not always restart my mongo server

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Check the below link once.

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61503/how-to-start-mongodb-server-on-system-start)